# How can a PSObject Show Size as GB when displayed as object but show as bytes when called as a property?

Tags: powershell

When I use Get-Volume

```
$Volume = Get-Volume
$Volume
```

I get the results

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
 R          Recovery     NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     482.8 MB    499 MB
```

When I call the property Size I get

```
$Volume.Size
```

I get the results

```
523235328
```

How can the property Size display the 499MB when I call the object but when I call the property directly It shows the int of bytes.

I have looked for a script property or alias, I do not see those in the `$Volume.PSObject.Properties` or `$Volume.PSObject.Methods`

Comment: The following links might be helpful to understand how that works [About Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1) and [About Types.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: I've included details for what Olaf suggests below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Trace-Command -Name * -Expression {Get-Volume C | Format-Table} -PSHost` returns a *lot* of information, including:

```
DEBUG: 2021-03-02 10:18:20.5439 FormatViewBinding Information: 0 :         MATCH FOUND Table NAME: VolumeTableView  TYPE: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Volume
```

Now, some will probably take issue with the clumsy way I get to the formatter for this, but here goes:

```
Get-FormatData -TypeName Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Volume |
  Select -Expand FormatViewDefinition |
  Select -Expand Control |
  Select -Expand Rows |
  Select -Expand Columns |
  Select -Expand DisplayEntry |
  Select -Expand Value
```

(Guess you could also do `(Get-FormatData -TypeName Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Volume).FormatViewDefinition.Control.Rows.Columns.DisplayEntry.Value`, but I'm not convinced that's a lot better.)

reveals a script value for a column entry of:

```
 $size = $_.Size;
 $postfixes = @( "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" )
 for ($i=0; $size -ge 1024 -and $i -lt $postfixes.Length; $i++) { $size = $size / 1024; }
 return "" + [System.Math]::Round($size,2) + " " + $postfixes[$i];
```

So, `Format-Table` is invoking a pre-defined formatter on your Size column that you don't get when selecting the value directly.

Comment: Great explanation

Comment: You can get the formatters in an easier way `$object | %{ Get-FormatData -TypeName ($_.psobject.typenames -replace '\[|\]') } `. Same approach is applicable for `Get-TypeData`.

Answer (score 4):

One is just screen formatting for human readability, the other is real data.

```
(Get-Disk)[0] | Get-Member
# Results
<#
...
Size                      Property       uint64 Size {get;}
...
#>

(Get-Volume)[0] | Get-Member
# Results
<#
...
Size                      Property       uint64 Size {get;}
...
#>

((Get-Disk)[0]).PSObject.Properties
# Results
<#
...
BaseObject      : MSFT_Disk (ObjectId = "{1}\\lab01\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storag...)
Tag             : AllocatedSize = 512109142016
MemberType      : Property
Value           : 512109142016
IsSettable      : False
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : uint64
Name            : AllocatedSize
IsInstance      : True

...

BaseObject      : MSFT_Disk (ObjectId = "{1}\\lab01\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storag...)
Tag             : Size = 512110190592
MemberType      : Property
Value           : 512110190592
IsSettable      : False
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : uint64
Name            : Size
IsInstance      : True

...
#>

((Get-Volume)[0]).PSObject.Properties
# Results
<#
...
BaseObject      : MSFT_Volume (ObjectId = "{1}\\lab01\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storag...)
Tag             : Size = 510815686656
MemberType      : Property
Value           : 510815686656
IsSettable      : False
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : uint64
Name            : Size
IsInstance      : True

BaseObject      : MSFT_Volume (ObjectId = "{1}\\lab01\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storag...)
Tag             : SizeRemaining = 312891092992
MemberType      : Property
Value           : 312891092992
IsSettable      : False
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : uint64
Name            : SizeRemaining
IsInstance      : True
...
#>
```

If you want to use the human-readable, regardless of how it is called, then you have to format that in your code or mess with the formatter files.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other answers regarding format types, if you just want the value displayed nicely in MB:

```
'{0:f0} MB' -f ($Volume.Size / 1MB)
```

This divides the value by `1048576` (1024<sup>2</sup>) and displays it with zero decimal places and the `MB` suffix.